# How to remove a string between the specific characters using regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have string like below,

```
$string = "test coontevt [gallery include=\"12,24\"] first [gallery include=\"12,24\"] second";
```

i need to remove the string starts with `[gallery` to  first ocuurance of it's `]`.

i already use this one,

```
$string12 = preg_replace('/[gallery.+?)+(/])/i', '', $string);
```

but i get empty string only.

Finally i want result for the above string is,

```
$string ="test coontevt first second".
```

How can i do this using regular expression?.

plz help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `[` is a regex meta-character. TO match a literal `[` you need to escape it.

```
$string12 = preg_replace('/\[gallery.+?\]/i', '', $string);
```

or

```
$string12 = preg_replace('/\[gallery[^\]]+\]/i', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the square brackets

```
$string12 = preg_replace('/\[gallery.+?\]/i', '', $string);
```

The round brackets are unnecessary so I removed them, also the quantifier between those brackets and the forward slash before the last square bracket.

To avoid multiple space in the result, I would match also the surrounding spaces and replace with 1 space.

`\s+\[gallery.+?\]\s+` and replace with one space

```
$string12 = preg_replace('/\s+\[gallery.+?\]\s+/i', ' ', $string);
```

See this expression here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vaje)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$string12 = preg_replace('/\[gallery[^\]]+\]/i', '', $string);
```

`[^\]]+` means that there can be one or more character that is not `]`. And there is no need for any `(` and `)` if you don't want to use the backreferences.